# Diferenças no build no jenkins?

Tags: java, linux, git, maven, jenkins

Configurei Jenkins para "buildar" um projeto a partir de um repositório git, eu estou usando maven:

> Warning: JAVA_HOME environment variable is not set. Apache Maven 3.3.3
>   (7994120775791599e205a5524ec3e0dfe41d4a06; 2015-04-22T08:57:37-03:00)
>   Maven home: /opt/maven Java version: 1.7.0_95, vendor: Oracle
>   Corporation Java home:
>   /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.95.x86_64/jre
>   Default locale:
>   en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8 OS name: "linux", version:
>   "2.6.32-573.el6.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

Tentei executar "setando" também a JAVA_HOME:

```
[root@centos64 ~]# mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.3.3 (7994120775791599e205a5524ec3e0dfe41d4a06; 2015-04-22T08:57:37-03:00)
Maven home: /opt/maven
Java version: 1.7.0_95, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.95.x86_64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "2.6.32-573.el6.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Quando eu executo o build pelo jenkins o build roda imcompleto:

[image]

Quando eu executo pelo terminal ele acontece correto:

[image]

Em ambos os casos o build é finalizado com sucesso.

Não sei exatamente o que está acontecendo.

Comment: Você configurou a variável de ambiente JAVA_HOME no linux? Pelo que eu entendi você "setou" o JAVA_HOME na configuração do maven

Comment: Eu executei export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.95.x86_64/jre depois export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu estava cometendo dois erros:

1 - Eu não estava especificando a branch correta no jenkins

2 - Por alguma razão, que eu não sei exatamente o porque, o pull não estava sendo executado, deletei meu workspace e recriei novamente, isso funcionou.

Obrigado a todos !